# Force drupal to return 200

Tags: drupal, http-status-code-404, custom-pages

Is it possible to link to a page that doesn't necessarily exists as drupal content and not get a 404 page not found.

Example:

link: example.com/search/projects?content="words"

There is no search/projects node or page so obviously it returns page not found although I can still run my queries inside that page.

Views would probably be a solution here but I sort of need more control on the outputted html and don't feel like going in to the views templates.

I guess my question is if it is possible to mimic views feature of creating pages which will aggregate content but don't have content theme selfs.

Is this possible at all? It seems pretty standard right? I have no idea ho to do it thought...

Answer (score 1):

You can create a menu item for search/projects and return anything you'd like.

http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer%21hooks%21core.php/function/hook_menu/6

should get you started.